# How to make R read thousands .txt files (Financial Reports) at once?

Tags: r

I am new to R and would like to have it read all the 10-K financial reports which are in .txt format and I want it to read all these files at once?

I have tried

```
dir<- "/Users/Documents/Edgar filings"
text = readtext(paste0(dir, "/ALL_2016/*.txt")
```

However, nothing happens, I mean no output is produced at the console section, and also there is no errors.

I tried to have it read only one 10-K report through

```
dir <- "/Users/Documents/Edgar filings"
text = readtext(paste0(dir, "/ALL_2016/10254_10-K_2016-03-11*.txt")
```

but again neither any output nor any error messages.

I tried it through quanteda

```
mycorpus <- corpus(textfile("~/ALL_10-K_2016/*.txt"))
```

but this time it says "textfile function is not available for 3.4.3" even though my R version is 3.4.4 which I updated a couple of weeks ago.

I also tried using `list.files()` but I do not know how to create a loop coding, so I just got stuck!

I highly appreciate if someone please help.

Comment: search for read folder CSV r

Comment: Have a look at my answer to [How to make a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061). It will tell you how to read the files into a list using `list.files` and then (if applicable) combine them into a single data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `readChar` with `vapply`:

1. store the folder path (note the `\` before the space)

`path <- "/Users/Documents/Edgar\ filings"`

2. store the fully specified file paths

`files <- file.path(path, list.files(path))`

3. read in all of the files

`documents <- vapply(X=1:length(files), FUN=function(i){
    readChar(files[i], file.info(files[i])$size)
    }, FUN.VALUE = character(1))`

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for your response but for the 3rd code I am having the following error: Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "rb") :
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection  do you have any suggestion for that please? Thanks again.

Comment: When I also run the second code, at the environment section under the values I get files character (empty). This might be the reason of not getting a result from the third code?

Comment: Make sure path in step 1 refers to the folder with the .txt files in it (and there are no other files in that folder). Then step 2 creates a vector with the fully specified file paths. After that, step 3 should run without error.

Comment: I re-installed R & Rstudio now the codes are working. However, when I run the codes I do not see the text documents that are read on my console. Is it ok or do I have to do sthg for that please? Thanks much for your help.

Comment: Step 3 stores the text documents in a vector named documents. To print the contents did you try either typing `print(documents)` or `documents`? Please do accept if the above answers your question.

Comment: It does process when I put "print(documents)" but R aborts the session by notifying that "fatal error occurred". Then ends the session automatically without showing me the content of the text. I think I will try another software coz whatever I do does not help. Thanks much for your time. I Appreciate.